# understanding mapDispatchToProps in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

i want my code to listen the choice(on list page) and then display the data by getting data from node server on another page

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {loadBickes} from './../../reducers/itemsGet.js'
import axios from 'axios'
class Hello extends React.Component{


constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleBick = this.handleBick.bind(this)
}

handleBick(){
    console.log("demanding bickes")
    //loadBickes();
    axios.get('/getBike')
        .then((response)=>{
        var dataP = response.data
        console.log("data set")
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log("redy to b dispatched set")
        {this.props.setState(response.data)}
    //    dispatch(setState(response.data))
    })
}
//                <h4><Link to="Bike" onClick={this.props.Bike}>Bicycle</Link></h4>

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Items</h1>

                <h4><button onClick={this.handleBick}>Bicycle</button></h4>
                <h4><Link to="Calculator" onClick={this.props.Calculator}>Calculator</Link></h4>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps =(state)=>{
    console.log("state"+state.item.name)
    return {
       user : state.item
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps =(dispatch)=>{
 return {
    Bike : () => dispatch({
      type : "LOAD_BIKE"
    }),
     Calculator : () => dispatch({
      type : "LOAD_CALC"
    }),
        setState:(data)=>dispatch({
            type : "setData",
            payload : data
        })
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Hello)
```

i mAke axios call to server and then i want to dispatch action to set state of my reducer and then i will try to redirect it to other page 
is their any other way
or 
i need 1) to give data of axios to dispatcher
2) way to redirect it after

help please

Comment: `this.props.history.push` is how you redirect to another route with React Router. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {loadBickes} from './../../reducers/itemsGet.js'
import axios from 'axios'

class Hello extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleBick = this.handleBick.bind(this)
    }

    handleBick(){
        axios.get('/getBike').then( (response) => {
            let dataP = response.data;
            this.props.setState(response.data);
            this.props.history.push("/route_you_want_to_go_too");
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Items</h1>

                <h4>
                    <button onClick={this.handleBick}>Bicycle</button>
                </h4>

                <h4>
                    <Link to="Calculator" onClick={this.props.Calculator}>Calculator</Link>
                </h4>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        user : state.item
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
        Bike : () => dispatch({
            type : "LOAD_BIKE"
        }),
        Calculator : () => dispatch({
            type : "LOAD_CALC"
        }),
        setState:(data)=>dispatch({
            type : "setData",
            payload : data
        })
});

export default connect( mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps )( Hello );
```

You should think about working on writing cleaner code, it will make it easier to help you.

Comment: thanku bro.this help me a lot and i will work on ur advice also